# How can each instance of a jQuery plugin have its own properties and methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, module-pattern

I am learning how to create jQuery plugins and have built one using module pattern.  It works if I apply it only once, however, if I apply multiple times, all of them get initialized using the last one's settings.

For instance, if I first do `$('#div1').myPlugin();`, and then later `$('#div2').myPlugin({myProperty  :'mydiv2Property'});`, `$('#div1')` myProperty is changed from myDefaultProperty to mydiv2Property.  The same thing happens when initializing with a different method.

I have a working (well, almost working!) example located at http://jsbin.com/eWePoro/1/, and my full script is listed below.

How do I change this script so each time the plugin is applied, it uses just its own properties and methods?  Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            (function($){
                var defaults = {
                    myProperty  :'myDefaultProperty',
                    myMethod1   :function () {
                        console.log('myMethod1',this,this.myProperty);
                    },
                    myMethod2   :function () {
                        console.log('myMethod2',this,this.myProperty);
                    }
                };

                var methods = {
                    init : function (options) {
                        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});
                        settings.myMethod1();
                        return this.each(function () {
                            $(this).click(function(e) {
                                settings.myMethod2();
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    destroy : function () {
                        //Anything else I should do here?
                        delete settings;
                        return this.each(function () {});
                    }
                };

                $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
                    if (methods[method]) {
                        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
                        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
                    } else {
                        $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
                    }    
                };

                }(jQuery)
            );
            $(function(){
                $('#div1').myPlugin();
                $('#div2').myPlugin({
                    myProperty  :'mydiv2Property'
                });
                $('#div3').myPlugin({
                    myMethod1   :function () {console.log('myMethod1_new',this,this.myProperty);}
                });
                 $('#div4').myPlugin({
                    myMethod2   :function () {console.log('myMethod2_new',this,this.myProperty);}
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='div1'>div1</div>
        <div id='div2'>div2</div>
        <div id='div3'>div3</div>
        <div id='div4'>div4</div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: @zeroflagL.  I think this was the document I originally used, but an older version.  Can't be sure however, and I will re-read it again.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});
```

You are actually modifying `defaults` here with new properties. So next time you run the same code, `defaults` will be mutated. You should probably do:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

This will create a new settings object every time by cloning `defaults` before extending it.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/eWePoro/2

Comment: David, Your awesome!  I originally got the faulting line of code from some tutorial (don't even remember were), and just never suspected it.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Answer is perfect.  If you see any other deficiencies in my script, please let me know.